# is it possible to iterate two items simultaneously using foreach in jstl?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, jsp, jstl

I have two items from my model and I want to iterate them at the same using jstl foreach. how can I achieve this using a correct syntax?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can call `varStatus.index` to get the index of the current round of iteration, and then use it as a lookup for the second list.

For example, if you have two lists `people.firstnames` and `people.lastnames` you can do:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${people.firstnames}" varStatus="status">
  <tr>
      <td>${p}</td>
      <td>${people.lastnames[status.index]}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Quite straight and clever approach. +1

Comment: Great, it works fine, but i have 3 lists, how to iterate third list?

Comment: @GaneshPutta, since you have the index already, you can apply the same logic on n number of lists. ```x[status.index]```, ```y[status.index]```, ```z[status.index]``` and so on.