# How to iterate through multiple Lists using JSTL foreach loop

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have this code to send two Lists for iterating

```
 request.setAttribute("PopulateAgentList", agentList);
 request.setAttribute("PopulateAgentContactList",agentContactList);
```

I can iterate through only one List usijng this code.

```
<c:forEach var="PopulateAgentList" items="${requestScope['PopulateAgentList']}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${PopulateAgentList.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${PopulateAgentList.country}"/></td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Can I iterate through the both "PopulateAgentContactList" and "PopulateAgentList".

Comment: That simply shows a design problem. Instead of having two parallel lists, you should have a single one , where each object inside the list would contain an agent and a contact.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [this answer here explains a way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4142885/765419)

In your situation, you would do something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="PopulateAgentList" items="${people.firstnames}" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${PopulateAgentList.name}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${PopulateAgentList.country}"/></td>
        <td><c:out value="${PopulateAgentContactList[status.index].whatever}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```