# How to iterate through multiple ArrayList using JSTL?

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose i have 3 arraylist like:

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("Q1");
list2.add("name1");
list3.add("abdur");
list1.add("Q2");
list2.add("name2");
list3.add("bappa");
```

now I want to display the above three arraylist element like:

```
Q1 name1 abdur
Q2 name2 bappa
```

How can i do that by `<c:forEach>` ..please help.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this?? Just masochism or is there some valid business case?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4142885/2173960) should solve your problem. But, even better would be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4821588/2173960) if you can change your data structures.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${list1}" var="element" varStatus="loop">    
    <c:out value="${element} ${list2[loop.index]} ${list3[loop.index]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @AbdurRahaman accept the answer if it helped so others can benefit from the same.